# 40-th iteration by FindRoot

Tags: equation-solving

I tried to compute the 40-th iteration by FindRoot but without result.
   Please If any body solve that, I would to thank him. This question has a 
   nonlinear system. And the solution for n=1 is solved. But there is problem 
   when n=2,3, ...40.

The following code for computing the four unknowns for the nonlinear system. 
   The four unknowns : u[0,n], u[1,n], u[2,n], u[3,n]  ?
   Initial conditions:

```
 u[0, 0] := 0.4720012157682348`; u[1, 0] := 0; 
 u[2, 0] := -0.4994032582704072`; u[3, 0] := 0;

 F1 = -u[0, n] + 99999.99999999999` (-u[0, -1 + n] + u[0, n]) + 
 0.7071067811865475` u[1, n] - 
 70710.67811865473` (-u[1, -1 + n] + u[1, n]) - 16.` u[2, n] - 
 2.775557561562891`*^-12 (-u[2, -1 + n] + u[2, n]) - 
 70710.67811865476` (u[3, -1 + n] - 1.` u[3, n]) + (u[0, n] - 
 0.7071067811865475` u[1, n] - 2.7755575615628914`*^-17 u[2, n] + 
 0.7071067811865477` u[3, n])^2 + 67.17514421272202` u[3, n]

F2 = 0.` - u[0, n] + 99999.99999999999` (-u[0, -1 + n] + u[0, n]) - 
0.7071067811865475` u[1, n] + 
70710.67811865473` (-u[1, -1 + n] + u[1, n]) - 16 u[2, n] + 
70710.67811865442` (u[3, -1 + n] - 1.` u[3, n]) + (0.` + u[0, n] + 
0.7071067811865475` u[1, n] - 0.7071067811865444` u[3, n])^2 - 
67.17514421272199` u[3, n]
F3 = u[0, n] - u[1, n] + u[2, n] - u[3, n]

F4 = u[0, n] + u[1, n] + u[2, n] + u[3, n]

n := 1

Sol = 
FindRoot[{F1 == 0, F2 == 0, F3 == 0, 
F4 == 0}, { {u[0, n], 0.4720012157682348`}, {u[1, n], 
0}, {u[2, n], -0.4994032582704072`}, {u[3, n], 0}}] // Flatten

 {u[0, 1] -> 0.4719281993760747, u[1, 1] -> 0., 
u[2, 1] -> -0.4719281993760747, u[3, 1] -> 0.}
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? What do you mean by 40th iteration? What is wrong with the output of `FindRoot`?

Comment: Please edit the original question instead of re-posting it. If you fix the problems with it, it will be re-opened, and people might withdraw their downvotes. The problem is still not explained in words.  Can you explain it in plain words, in such a way that it will be mostly understandable without having to read the code?

Comment: Thank you for advices. Actually I am new to this site. Yes I repeated this question, since I could not edit the last question because the icons not active. So I resent it and edited and added the question in the body of the post. This question has a nonlinear system. And the solution for n=1 is solved. But there is problem when n=2,3, ...40.

Comment: @Khaled your issue is in how you defined `F1`, `F2`, `F3` and `F4`. Their explicit dependence of `u[_,1]` is the problem. You will want them to depend on `u[_,n]` instead. I suggest converting each into, e.g. `F1[n_]` where it constructs the expression with appropriate dependence on `n`. Then also make `Sol` a function, like `Sol[n_]`, where you use `F1[n]==0`, `F2[n]==0`, etc.

Comment: Thank you b3m2a1. I tried but without results.

Comment: Thanks anderstood. No problem with n=1. But when n=2, ..., we could not get anything.

Comment: I corrected and edited the code. I think now is clear.

Comment: I added yesterday 2 comments.  I couldn't see it. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the `F`s defined as in the question, one way to iterate the calculation is

```
Sol = { u[0, 0] -> 0.4720012157682348`, u[1, 0] -> 0, 
    u[2, 0] -> -0.4994032582704072`, u[3, 0] -> 0};
Do[Sol = FindRoot[{F1, F2, F3, F4} /. Sol, 
    {{u[0, n], 0.4720012157682348`}, {u[1, n], 0}, {u[2, n], -0.4994032582704072`}, 
     {u[3, n], 0}}] // Flatten // Chop; Print[Sol], {n, 40}]

(* {u[0,1]->0.471928,u[1,1]->0,u[2,1]->-0.471928,u[3,1]->0} 
   {u[0,2]->0.471855,u[1,2]->0,u[2,2]->-0.471855,u[3,2]->0}
    ...
   {u[0,39]->0.469162,u[1,39]->0,u[2,39]->-0.469162,u[3,39]->0}
   {u[0,40]->0.46909,u[1,40]->0,u[2,40]->-0.46909,u[3,40]->0} *)
```

Whether the results should be printed, as here, saved in an array, or post-processed in some way depends on how the results are to be used.

Comment: Thank you very much bbgodfrey.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want something like that:

```
fr1[0] = {u[0, 0] -> 0.4720012157682348`, u[1, 0] -> 0,
          u[2, 0] -> -0.4994032582704072`, u[3, 0] -> 0}

F1[n_] = -u[0, n] + 99999.99999999999` (-u[0, -1 + n] + u[0, n]) + 
         0.7071067811865475` u[1, n] - 
        70710.67811865473` (-u[1, -1 + n] + u[1, n]) - 16.` u[2, n] - 
        2.775557561562891`*^-12 (-u[2, -1 + n] + u[2, n]) - 
        70710.67811865476` (u[3, -1 + n] - 1.` u[3, n]) + (u[0, n] - 
        0.7071067811865475` u[1, n] - 2.7755575615628914`*^-17 u[2, n] + 
        0.7071067811865477` u[3, n])^2 + 67.17514421272202` u[3, n]
```

Define the F2,F3,F4 the same way

Calculate a table of FindRoot solutions fr1[n], each time inserting fr1[n-1]

```
tab = Union[{fr1[0]}, 
       Table[fr1[n] = 
         FindRoot[{F1[n] == 0, F2[n] == 0, F3[n] == 0, F4[n] == 0} /. 
            fr1[n - 1], {{u[0, n], 1}, {u[1, n], 
            1}, {u[2, n], -1}, {u[3, n], 1}}], {n, 1, 40}]] // Flatten;
```

Plot the solution points

```
Table[ListPlot[Table[u[j, n] /. tab, {n, 0, 40}]], {j, 0, 3}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Akku14.